# Raspberry Pi 4B - Is Device tree binary dependent on kernel version?

Tags: linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, device-tree

I am trying to get my own custom Linux on a Raspberry Pi 4B. My status is this:

I built the Linux 5.9.1 version, and have my own version of U-Boot, RFS with which **I am able to successfully load and start the kernel, mount RFS, as well as reach the Kernel console also**. The device tree binary I used here was one which I built in the Kernel environment using the .dts, .dtsi files for bcm2711 (and a few dependencies which popped up during the build) that I took from [Raspberry Pi GITHub Linux page](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/tree/rpi-5.9.y)

Now I later discovered that for my purpose I had to use Linux 5.6.19 and so I downloaded that and built it too. I decided to use the same .dtb, but strangely now I don't go beyond the step of Starting Kernel... (See screenshot)
[image]

Is the device tree binary specific for every Kernel version that we intend to use?

If yes, What should I do to get the files specific for Linux 5.6.19 version? I tried using the version from rpi-5.6.y branch on the Raspberry Pi GitHub - it did not help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post text as text. Pictures of text is hard to read: Blind people can't read it. Search engines can't read it. Others can't change font, show in higher resolution, copy, or search.

Answer (score 0):

afaik device tree is specific for every kernel version.

e.g. for `arm` platform, based on your kernel config you will find `dtbs` here

`arch/arm/boot/dts`

However, looking at the prompt my hunch is you are missing `kernel bootargs`

You can stop the booting at the u-boot and double check the `u-boot's env` for `kernel bootargs`

If you can provide `printenv` output in the u-boot, I can tell you more information about that...